# Verify PushTopics are firing

Tags: pushtopic

Is there a way to check whether PushTopics are pushing their topics? I have verified that the PushTopics exist in the database

```
SELECT Name,Query FROM PushTopics
```

But is there a straightforward way to verify that the PushTopic has fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I can do this trivially with Workbench.

https://workbench.developerforce.com/

If you go to that link and provide your Salesforce credentials, it allows you to subscribe to PushTopics from your org and examine the XML being pushed.

To check this out, you should access the "queries" menu, and click on "Streaming Push Topics". On the screen you can select the available push topics in your organization, and monitor the events from there.

Comment: This is more of a comment unless you care to expand with details on how to use the link to do what the OP needs

Comment: Updated to include actual answer.

Comment: This is pretty useful, but all I get is a ton of handshake events and nothing else. What should I expect when a push topic is published?